# Accounting for character size difference

Tags: html, css, fonts, character

So, supposing that i have to fill the space below (Of a definite width) with characters:
-----------------------
AAAAAAAAAAA (11 Characters cover it when these characters are all uppercased As)
-----------------------
aaaaaaaaaaaaa (13 Characters cover it when they are lowercased as)

Is there any way i can account for these differences and adjust my width in HTML accordingly? (So my program would read the characters and the resulting "width" from the sentence)

The problem lies in which characters are used, the user can input everything from simple letters to numbers and special characters, is there a definite known solution for this problem?

Edit.:
(Using a monospace font is not an option)

Comment: use a monospace font?

Comment: Yes, but i'm afraid that's not an option

Comment: Are you trying to make it so the letters fill the full width?  What's the end goal?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to make the letters reach almost the full width, they can have 255 characters, but with 255 characters and the actual font-size they overflow horizontally and ruin the layout of my page, so i'm trying to limit it.

Comment: Ok you need js then if it  is to stop it overflowing (to calculate the width of letters vs width of container) - or you could use [ellispsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) if it is only one line of text, or you could force the [word to break and wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) or you could just set a width on the div and hide the overflow

Comment: Even then, 11 uppercase A's are not exactly the same size as 13 lowercase a's.

Comment: I think you might need to explain *why* you want to do this in more detail. At the moment there is no CSS method to do this. You will need Javascript. This sounds lke an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Warning, only works in Firefox, at time of post:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-justify

If you can't use a monospace font, then you could try using CSS `text-align: justify;`, `text-align-last: justify;` and `text-justify: inter-character;` on a container `<div>` to ajust the spacing between the lowercase a's to make it the same width as the same number of uppercase A's:

```css
.justify {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  text-justify: inter-character;
}
```

```html
<h4>Before:</h4>
<div>
  <span>AAAAAAAAAAA</span>
  <br>
  <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
</div>
<h4>After:</h4>
<div class="justify">
  <span>AAAAAAAAAAA</span>
  <br>
  <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
</div>
```

***Note that you will also need a `display: inline-block` on the container `<div>` so that the letter spacing doesn't expand to take up the whole width of the screen. eg***

[image]